# A "Subjected case"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I usually see the following phrases when someone from support team contacts me or my team for help:

> Need help with the subjected case

or

> I am contacting you regarding the subjected case

or

> Please look at the subjected case

And the `Subject:` line of the mail will usually have `Case #<a-5-or-6-digit-case-ID>`

They probably mean they need help with the case ID [in the subject] ?
Is the usage "subjected case" correct ?

Comment: There isn’t a “correct” or “incorrect” in English so much as “used” or “unused” (with a huge spectrum in between, regional variations, etc). In that sense, no, I haven’t seen this usage before, though I understood it without any further context beyond “it was in an email”; if encountered it in the wild I’d probably assume it’s from an L2 speaker (at a guess, from the Indian subcontinent).

Comment: It's not idiomatic in the US. The recipient knows there's a case in hand, and the subject line lists the ID. So why mention more? Also, *subjected* is not the thing in the Subject line. All that's needed is “I am contacting you regarding your case.” It insults the reader to say you're *addressing the thing you're addressing, as shown above in the aforementioned title ID of your case*.

Comment: This seems like a neologism that's easier to type than "case in the subject".

Comment: I think they mean the case [in the subject line].

Comment: Someone can be CCed or BCCed by filling in the CC or BCC field, but it's a stretch from there to say something can be subjected by putting it in the subject field.

Comment: I'd be ok with calling this one "incorrect."  Not only is it not idiomatic, it's also confusing.

Comment: @StuartF It sounds to me like a generalization of those terms by a non-native Engilsh speaker. Or maybe it's jargon in their organization that they've let loose in the wild.

Comment: @cruthers I agree with you - it is confusing because "subjected" implies the verb "to subject" which has a very different meaning than the noun "subject"